# Accessing Sub functions /procedures from DPR or other function / procedure in Delphi

Tags: delphi, access-specifier, subroutine

As much I know - Subroutines are with Private access mode to its parent unction / procedure, right?

Is there any way to access them from "outer-world" - dpr or other function / procedure in unit?

Also - which way takes more calcualtion and space to compiled file?

for example:

```
function blablabla(parameter : tparameter) : abcde;
 procedure xyz(par_ : tpar_);
 begin
  // ...
 end;
begin
 // ...
end;

procedure albalbalb(param : tparam) : www;
begin
 xyz(par_ : tpar_); // is there any way to make this function public / published to access it therefore enabling to call it this way?
end;

// all text is random.

// also, is there way to call it from DPR in this manner?

// in C++ this can be done by specifing access mode and/or using "Friend" class .. but in DELPHI?
```

Comment: Private is private :) Are you looking for a way to make it public without changing the code?

Comment: It's not even private, it is internal. It does not exist outside of the "parent" routine where it's embedded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Embedded Routines <> Private/Protected Methods.

Embedded routines i.e. routines inside routines can not be accessed by external routines.
You have posted an example of an Embedded routine, I also heard them called Internal Routines.

Here is another example:

```
procedure DoThis;

function DoThat : Boolean;
begin
  // This Routine is embedded or internal routine.
end;
begin

// DoThat() can only be accessed from here no other place.

end;
```

Regardless of visibility, methods on classes,  can be called using Delphi 2010 via RTTI.   I have detailed how to do this in [this article](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/exploring-trttimember-descendants-in_17.html).

If you are in the same Unit methods on a class can be accessed by any other code regardless of visibility, unless they are marked with Strict Private.   [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516493/difference-between-strict-private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-delphi) has more details and good example code in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516493/difference-between-strict-private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-delphi/1516551#1516551).

If you are in two different units you can use the Protected Method Hack to access the protected methods.   Which is detailed in detailed in [this article](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Nested procedures/functions - those declared inside another procedure or function, are a special type, because they can access the stack (and thereby parameters/local variables) of the procedure they are nested in. Because of this, and Delphi scope rules, there is no way to access them outside the "parent" procedure. You use them only if you need to take advantage of their special features. AFAIK Delphi/Pascal is one of the few languages to have this feature. From a compiler point of view the call has some extra code to allow accessing the parent stack frame, IIRC.
AFAIK "friend" class/functions in C++ are different - they are class access methods, while in your example you are using plain procedures/functions.
In Delphi all procedure/classes declared in the same unit are automatically "friend", unless **strict private** declarations are used in latest Delphi releases. For example this code snippets will work, as long everything is in the same unit:

```
  type
    TExample = class
    private
      procedure HelloWorld;
    public
    ...
    end;

  implementation

    function DoSomething(AExample: TExample);
    begin
      // Calling a private method here works
      AExample.HelloWordl;
    end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can access a subroutine, which is nested in other (parent) subroutine, from the outer world. Though it's somewhat tricky. I've found this howto in the web.

**How to pass nested routine as a procedural parameter (32 bit)**

Delphi normally does not support passing nested routines as procedural parameters:

```
// This code does not compile:
procedure testpass(p: tprocedure);
begin
  p;
end;
procedure calltestpass;
 procedure inner;
 begin
   showmessage('hello');
 end;
begin
  testpass(inner);
end;
```

The obvious workaround is to pass procedure address and typecast it within testpass:

```
// This code compiles and runs OK
procedure testpass(p: pointer);
begin
  tProcedure(p);
end;
procedure calltestpass;
 procedure inner;
 begin
   showmessage('hello');
 end;
begin
  testpass(@inner);
end;
```

There is, however, a  pitfall in the above example - if the "inner" routine references any variable that was pushed onto the stack before the "inner" procedure was called from testpass (calltestpass parameters - if there were any, or local variables in calltestpass - if there were any), your system most probably crashes:

```
// This code compiles OK but generates runtime exception (could even be
//  EMachineHangs :-) )
procedure testpass(p: pointer);
begin
  tProcedure(p);
end;
procedure calltestpass;
var msg: string;
 procedure inner;
 begin
   msg := 'hello';
   showmessage(msg);
 end;
begin
  testpass(@inner);
end;
```

The reason is, in simple words, that the stack frame arrangement
was "broken" by the call to testpass routine and "inner" procedure
incorrectly calculates parameters and local variables location
(do not blame Delphi, please).
The workaround is to set up the correct stack context before
"inner" is called from within "testpass".

```
// This code compiles and runs OK
{$O-}
procedure testpass(p: pointer);
var callersBP: longint;
begin
  asm // get caller's base pointer value at the very beginning
    push dword ptr [ebp]
    pop callersBP
  end;
// here we can have some other OP code
  asm // pushes caller's base pointer value onto stack and calls tProcedure(p)
    push CallersBP
    Call p
    Pop  CallersBP
  end;
// here we can have some other OP code
end;
{$O+}

procedure calltestpass;
var msg: string;
 procedure inner;
 begin
   msg := 'hello';
   showmessage(msg);
 end;
begin
  testpass(@inner);
end;
```

Please note the optimization is switched OFF for testpass routine - optimization generally does not handle mixed OP/assembler code very well.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do what you're asking. The `xyz` function is callable *only* by the enclosing `blablabla` function. Outside that function, `xyz` is not in scope and there is no way to name it. If C++ allowed nested function, there wouldn't be any way to refer to it, either, just like there's no way to refer to functions with static linkage from outside the current translation unit.

If you need to call `xyz` from outside the `blablabla` function, then move `xyz` outside. If you need to call it from outside the current unit, then you need to declare that function in the unit's interface section. Then, add that unit to the external code's `uses` clause and you can call `xyz` from wherever you want, even the DPR file.

If `xyz` refers to variables or parameters of the `blablabla` function, then you'll need to pass them in as parameters since `xyz` will no longer have access to them otherwise.

The concept of *access specifiers* isn't really relevant here since we're not talking about classes. Units have *interface* and *implementation* sections, which aren't really the same as *public* and *private* sections of a class.