# Delphi access modifiers

Tags: delphi

What is the Delphi equivalent for java's Default Modifier and how it is used.

or

what is the modifier that can only accessed in its current unit

---

***Update 1 after Remy Lebeau - TeamB's Answer***

---

what is the java's private equivalent in Delphi

Comment: It's all explained here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects   but there is no direct equivalent to java's private because that's a different environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition, `private` and even `strict private` *fields of other instances can be accessed from code within their class*

This is the same behaviour as in Java.

For an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8383009/80901)

Answer (score 7):

Delphi's default access specifier is `published` if the class has the `{$M+}` directive applied to it (directly or on an ancestor class that it derives from), otherwise it is `public` instead. To declare a class member so it can only be accessed within its declaring unit, you need to use the `private` access specifier.

Comment: Thanks , So what is the java's private equivalent in Delphi

Answer (score 1):

They are four:  private, protected,  public and published

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TControl)
    private
      { private declarations here }
    protected
      { protected declarations here }
    public
      { public declarations here }
    published
      { published declarations here }
  end;
```

Visibility of Class Members
Every member of a class has an attribute called visibility, which is indicated by one of the reserved words private, protected, public, published, or automated

source...
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members

Answer (score 0):

It's **Private** only. Three are Public, Published, Private.