# Is safe to set a private/protected/public method as event handler?

Tags: delphi, access-modifiers, eventhandler

While assigning event handlers, I've noticed that the `Object Inspector` allows to choose only between methods who have not an explicit access modifier.

Taking the following class as example:

```
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    MyButton: TButton;
    procedure MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure MyButtonPrivateClick(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure MyButtonProtectedClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure MyButtonPublicClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;
```

In the dropdown list, the `Object Inspector` shows only `MyButtonClick`:

[image]

Due to this reason, I'm wondering if it's safe to set a `private`/`protected`/`public` method to an event handler by code or if there could be some problems deriving from this practice.

```
MyButton.OnClick := MyButtonPrivateClick;
//...
```

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: @Lloyd: It seems nothing wrong, it compiles without errors neither warnings and it works but I don't know if there could be some backside aspect that would cause issues in particular conditions

Comment: The method is published. This is why you see it in the object inspector and not others.

Comment: Object Inspector shows MyButtonClick only, because it is the only published method here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380775/delphi-access-modifiers). From the code you can assign it as you need/want.

Comment: The reason the OI only shows the top one (published as mentioned before) as because only those can be set by the dfm streaming mechanism.

Comment: In Delphi, the default access of class members is `published` unless specified otherwise. This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly safe without having to worry about any hidden issues. This is especially common when writing a custom component (as opposed to a form) which has a sub-component inside of it, for example. You can put it virtually anywhere you want, but I suggest to keep it under `private`.